# Eclipse content assist validation key

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut, content-assist

I'm unable to find any documentation about changing the shortcut that validates the content assist selection.

I mean, for my exact case, when the content assist is opened, I want to validate its proposal by hitting enter (which works), but never with any other key, like . [ or (. I would like to choose what key validates the proposal.

Even if I need to manually edit a config file, if anyone have this answer, it would be perfect !

I looked at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs and org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.prefs but with no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are out of luck. The Eclipse Mars documentation discusses the content assist, stating:

```
Completion can be triggered by user request or can be automatically
 triggered when the "(" or "." character is typed:

public char[] getCompletionProposalAutoActivationCharacters() {
    return new char[] { '.', '(' };
}
```

Since it looks like these characters are hardcoded, you will need to implement your own content assist. Perhaps a simple derivative of the existing one with just this one method overwritten would suffice?