# "Enter" key in Content Assist?

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

Is there a way to stop Content Assist from "entering" the suggested choices when I press `space`? I only want the actual `enter` key to have this function.

There are others who asked this but haven't received a response. I was wondering if there was a fix to this now or maybe the question wasn't viewed by users who knew the fix?

[Disable statement completion on space in Eclipse Content Assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586771/disable-statement-completion-on-space-in-eclipse-content-assist)

[Eclipse content assist validation key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834950/eclipse-content-assist-validation-key)